# Find area of triangle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

This is from an italian math competition.

In the rectangle below:

[image]

area of yellow, green and red triangles are 27, 35 and 40 resepectively. What is the area of the blue triangle ?

My trial: I tried to define $a,b,c$ and $d$:

$a(c+d)=80 \tag{1}$

$bc=70 \tag{2}$

$d(a+b)=54 \tag{3}$

(to clarify, a is the length of the side of the red triangle and b of the green triangle which lie on the top of the rectangle. c and d are the lengths of the sides of the green and yellow triangle lying on the right side of the rectangle )

This is a system of 3 equations in 4 unknowns. We can observe that if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution, so is $(ak,bk,c/k,d/k)$. We can therefore fix the value of one variable, $a=1$, solve the system, and obtain $b=5/4, c=56, d=24$.

The area of the entire rectangle would than be $R=(a+b)(c+d)=180$, and the blue area $78$.

This solution works, but I think it requires too many calculations for the type of competition. Is there a smarter/quicker way ?

Comment: Formatting tip: Use `\tag{}` to tag equations.

Comment: $c=\frac{70}{b}$ and $d=\frac{54}{a+b}$. Substitute these in $(1)$ to get a quadratic expression in $a$ and $b$. Solve it to obtain a linear relation in $a$ and $b$. Hence obtain the value of $(a+b)(c+d)$ and subsequently the area of blue triangle.

Comment: @RiverX15 thanks a lot. I am not sure it is quicker than what I did though ...

Comment: There is [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K_j4Cj7mVo) but it too is not that simple.

Comment: Was it a multiple-choice question?

Comment: @MathLover actually no it is an open question, as far as I know

Comment: @MathLover you can find it here (prob. 15) https://giochimatematici.unibocconi.it/images/campionati/2021/Testi_Finale_110921.pdf , even if it is in italian

Comment: Got it, I do not see a simpler way to solve than making a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes simple if you see the trick. Let the height of the rectangle be $a$ and the width be $b$. Assign the shortest side of red $c$ and shortest side of yellow $d$. You will have, $d=\frac{54}{b}$ and $c=\frac{70}{a}$. Also you have, $(b-c)(a-d)=80 (1)$. Now, the area of triangle $A = ab - 102$.

If $x=ab$, substituting $c$ and $d$ is $(1)$ we get $(x-70)(x-54)=80x$. Solve the quadratic equation for $x$ and you will get $A$

Comment: Thank you for your contribution (+1), even if I would consider this more or less as 'computationally expensive' as my solution...